Adding languages base on the computer in RDS environment
I'm assigning keyboard languages to users in an RDS environment based on the host.
For example, if a user is assigned to ts "tsA", spanish will be added to the keyboard. Uf assigned to other ts spanish will not be assigned.
Languages are assigned by user but not by computer, and I can't create a GPO to specific users out because all users have access to each collection, and I need some way to run on all users and add the language based on the ts.
Right now the idea I'm thinking of is creating a GPO that will run a PowerShell script that will add and remove based on the hostname
# Get the name of the VM
$vmName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name

# Language to add/remove
$lang = "es-ES"

# Get the current language list
$languageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList

# Check if the VM name indicates it's a Spanish environment
if ($vmName -like "*tsA*") {
    # Check if Spanish keyboard layout is already installed
    if (-not ($languageList.LanguageTag -contains $lang)) {
        # Install Spanish keyboard layout
        $languageList.Add($lang)
        Set-WinUserLanguageList $languageList -Force

        Write-Output "Spanish keyboard layout installed and set as default."
    } else {
        Write-Output "Spanish keyboard layout is already installed."
    }
} else {
    # Check if Spanish keyboard layout is installed and remove it
    if ($languageList.LanguageTag -contains $lang) {
        $languageList = $languageList | Where-Object { $_.LanguageTag -ne $lang }
        Set-WinUserLanguageList $languageList -Force

        Write-Output "Spanish keyboard layout removed."
    } else {
        Write-Output "This VM does not require the Spanish keyboard layout."
    }
}

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?
Better than a logon script.
If you have more questions I am happy to answer.

Is it possible?
